# Is the WITH (NOLOCK) hint ignored on the non-target tables of an UPDATE or DELETE statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server Databases, the WITH (NOLOCK) query hint is ignored on target tables in UPDATE and DELETE statements.  However, does this also apply to tables included in a join for an update or delete?  For instance, is:

```
update t
set value1 = 123
FROM mytable t
inner join othertable o with (nolock) on t.id = o.id
```

equivalent to:

```
update t
set value1 = 123
FROM mytable t
inner join othertable o on t.id = o.id
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `NOLOCK` anyway? Side note: you put the hint in the wrong place, it needs to be immediately after the table reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not ignored. This is easy to test.

### Setup

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable, othertable

CREATE TABLE mytable(id INT, value1 INT)
CREATE TABLE othertable(id INT, dirtyvalue INT)

INSERT mytable VALUES (1, NULL)
INSERT othertable  VALUES (1, 100)
```

### Connection 1

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE othertable SET dirtyvalue = 999

WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00' /*To give time to run connection 2*/

ROLLBACK
```

### Connection 2 (whilst above still running)

```
update t
set value1 = o.dirtyvalue
output inserted.value1
FROM mytable t
inner join othertable o  with (nolock) on t.id = o.id
```

The uncommitted `999` value is used in the update rather than `100` as would have happened without the hint if running at RCSI or being blocked if running at RC locking isolation level.

Note the `999` value is never actually committed to `othertable` so the use of `NOLOCK` here means that the state persisted in `mytable` never logically existed.